# Factory Design Pattern with Dependency Injection in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I'm trying to use the factory design pattern in Angular, but I think I'm doing something wrong, or at least wondering if there's a better way. I have a factory which returns a car class depending on the type the user specifies (e.g., "mazda" returns a Mazda class, and "ford" returns a Ford class). Each car class uses multiples services.

```
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private logService: LogService
  ) {}

  create(
    info
  ):
    | Mazda
    | Tesla
    | Ford
    switch (info.type) {
      case 'mazda':
        return new Mazda(info, this.userService, this.logService);
      case 'tesla':
        return new Tesla(info, this.userService, this.logService);
      case 'ford':
        return new Ford(info, this.userService, this.logService);
    }
  }
}
```

My issue is when I'm creating the factory in a component, I need to inject the dependencies.

`this.carFactory = new CarFactory(this.userService, this.logService);`

It seems weird that my component would need to know about which dependencies my factory needs. Is there a way to create a factory in Angular where you don't need to inject the dependencies into the factory? Something like
`this.carFactory = new CarFactory();`

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this as following.

1. Declare above class as provider (Mazda,Tesla,Ford)
2. In factory class inject 1 dependancy "Injector".
3. In create function return as following

```
return this.injector.get(Tesla)
```

by this way you can resolve your dependancy dynamically.

Comment: I updated my example code to more accurately reflect what I need. Each derived class needs "info" passed into the constructor. This won't work if I use ```return this.injector.get(Tesla)``` for example, since i need to also pass "info" to the Tesla constructor. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could define the CarFactory as a dependency:

```
@Injectable(providedIn: 'root') // or provided wherever you need it
export class CarFactory {...}
```

and then just inject it, where you want to use it:

```
constructor(private carFactory: CarFactory) {
  const car = carFactory.create({type: 'tesla'});
}
```

Since the CarFactory is a dependency in the dependency injection hierarchy, it can inject, whatever is provided in this part of the Angular app.